# How to use DatabaseConnector connect with Hive in R in CDSW

Tags: r, hive, database-connection, data-quality, cdsw

I am trying to connect to Hive using the DatabaseConnector but unable to do so in R within CDSW. Can anyone please suggest how to accomplish this?

Please note that when using the driver and url, I am able to connect with hive and query the same successfully. Its just that when I am using the DatabaseConnector::createConnectionDetails() function, I am unable to query hive.

**Manual *Working* method to link Hive below:**

```
driver <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver","/path/to/CDH/Parcels/HiveJar", identifier.quote="`")
url <- "jdbc:hive2://HiveServerDetails:PORT/DBName;principal=hive/_HOST@domain.com;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;ssl=true;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2"
conn <- dbConnect(driver,url)
show_databases <- dbGetQuery(conn, "show databases")

show_databases
```

***Not working* method based on above using DatabaseConnector:**

```
connectionDetails <- DatabaseConnector::createConnectionDetails(dbms = "hive", user="", password = "", server = "jdbc:hive2://HiveServerDetails:PORT/DBName;principal=hive/_HOST@domain.com;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;ssl=true;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2", port = "PORT", pathToDriver="/jdbcdrivers")
```

Gives me the below error:

[Hive not getting linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG47f.png)

Would be really helpful if anyone can please suggest how to overcome this scenario.

Comment: Hi All, Bumping this thread. Can anyone please help in this regard? I'm kind of stuck here. Please advise.